# Code optimization for React (forEach or simply for)

Tags: reactjs

I've just finished building a React demo app and thought of doing a few optimizations, such as replacing the `forEach` iterations with simple `for`'s.

But while I was doing this I realized that I'm compiling the application with `webpack`, from what I know webpack runs everything through `babel`, so I was wondering, does this process turn the `forEach`'s and all the other *modern code* into *fast running code*?

Because I think that's a wonderful idea, to use `forEach` for the easier coding and then have it compiled to the fastest version.

Comment: To compile your code using `@babel` you need to use a `loader` with _Webpack_, so as default _Webpack_ isn't using it.

Comment: Just had the idea to compile the application and look into the build files to identify what is happening with everything, apparently you are right, I think, the ```forEach```'s are still there. If I would add Babel, would this compile everything like I've said? And if yes, any idea why its not already included? I assume most things would run much faster that way.

Comment: Try it out yourself: https://babeljs.io/en/repl

Comment: That's a good point, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel is going to change it for older browsers if your configure it so, in this specific case `forEach` is supported by all browsers even in older versions, Babel is not going to change it.

Comment: Ah, true and too bad, would have been a interesting thing to have such conversions occur so that we don't have to manually go through everything to make things run faster :)
Maybe have some sort or 'babel-like' site or webpack / npm package that just goes through everything and returns a faster version when slow codes are used!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using @babel/preset-env, which Create React App does, then the processing done by babel depends on what you have set in your .browserslistrc - and according to can i use https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach unless you are supporting IE8 or earlier, foreach should not be converted to a for loop.

Default create-react-app browserlist does not support IE8.

```
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```